# Most recent and next most recent values in a column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

[image]I'm using:
=FILTER(B:B,ROW(B:B)=MAX(FILTER(ROW(B:B),NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)))))

Edit: To clarify. I am looking to get the most recent value from B, the 2nd most recent value from B, and the most recent value from A where B is not blank. In my example, the most recent from B is 218, the 2nd most recent is 224.4, and the most recent from A where B is not blank is 12/30/14.
Ex:

```
blank
blank
VALUE1 <--- 2nd to max
blank
blank
...variable number of blanks
VALUE2 <-- max
```

Comment: I edited to clarify, large would work if I was trying to obtain the highest value and 2nd highest value, but I'm looking at something where rows are added sequentially. The values themselves aren't important, but essentially I want the value of the 2nd largest row value where the B column isn't blank.

Comment: Same issue, large is going to give the greater of two number's values, but in this particular case the values need to be treated as text. The max is essentially the row where the value is not blank.

Comment: I've added some clarification and an image. Your most recent example returns a blank because there are going to be dates with blank weights in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the Title:

> **the most recent value from B**

```
=vlookup(1E+100,B:B,1)
```

> **the 2nd most recent value from B**

```
=index(B:B,MATCH(1E+100,INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(1E+100,B:B)-1)))
```

> **the most recent value from A where B is not blank**

```
=index(A:A,MATCH(1E+100,INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH(1E+100,B:B))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I updated the title to reflect what I was trying to ask. =)

Comment: What does the 1E+100 in the match represent?